# Opening ms-settings from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

<--------------EDIT:-------------->

I can't use Windows.System

That assembly (and associated classes and namespaces) are for Windows Store apps only.

You cannot use them in a standard C# project.

Reference on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.launcher.aspx).

Also, the first part of the question has been answered:

If it sounds simple, it is.

Process.Start("ms-settings:SomePage");

So, now the question is, how do you get that to launch inside the WPF Page/Window?

<--------------/EDIT-------------->

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to develop a WPF application.  I'd prefer to use C# to launch the ms-settings:whatever page.

Ok, so I'm trying to follow the directions listed [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) on msdn.microsoft, but the assembly they reference "Windows.System" doesn't seem to exist. 0.o

"System.Windows" exists, but it doesn't contain Launcher.LaunchUriAsync...

Below is the snippet of code on that page:

```
using Windows.System;
...
bool result = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-webcam"));
```

So the question is, what am I missing?  I'm pretty sure something is flying way over my head and I can't seem to see what is.

Bonus points if you know how to get the ms-settings app to open *inside* the WPF page, although I'm pretty sure that isn't reasonably feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Windows treats the `ms-settings:...` syntax as URI. So, you should be able to open it in the default browser just as you would open any other URI from within C# code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ms-settings:privacy-webcam");
```

However, I'm not sure how older versions of Windows (which don't know the `ms-settings:...` syntax) react to that...

Comment: ha, answered my own question at the same time as you.  IDK why I didn't try the most obvious solution. *faceplam*

The next question is, how do you get that app to launch inside the WPF Page/Window?

Comment: If it doesn't work for someone then must add `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Damn, well I found why I can't use Windows.System

That assembly (and associated classes and namespaces) are for Windows Store apps only.

You cannot use them in a standard C# project.

Reference on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.launcher.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other solutions in this thread, but none of them worked on my Win10.

This method ended up working:

```
            var process = new Process();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "explorer.exe",
                Arguments = @"ms-availablenetworks:"
            };

            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```